# How to flex two <div> horizontally, with the same width?

Tags: html, css

I am writing a section of a webpage, and want to flex contents inside the same div horizontally, with equal width. Somehow my CSS code is not working.

```
const Reasons = ()=>{
    return (
        <div className="reasons" id='reasons'>
            <div className="left-r">
                <img src={image1} alt="" />
                <img src={image2} alt="" />
                <img src={image3} alt="" />
                <img src={image4} alt="" />

            </div>
            <div className="right-r">
                Right Side
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The CSS code:

```
.Reasons{
    padding: 0 2rem;
    display: flex;
}

.left-r{
    flex: 1 1;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.right-r{
    flex: 1 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: var(--orange);
}
```

I expect it to be flexing horizontally. But somehow it displays vertically.

[The webpage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dedUr.jpg)

Comment: Reasons is not the same as reasons.

Comment: Class names are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the className (`.reasons` instead of `.Reasons`), set a width for the images so that they remain in the horizontal direction, and also added some codes to crop the height if your images have different aspect ratio.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.reasons{
    padding: 0 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.left-r{
    flex: 1 1;

    /* Use the below codes if your images have different heights. If the images have identical heights then remove these codes */
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

/* Setting the image width to keep them in horizontal direction */
.left-r img{
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
}

.right-r{
    flex: 1 1;
    background-color: var(--orange);            
}
```

```html
<div class="reasons" id='reasons'>
    <div class="left-r">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/400?random=1" alt="" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/300?random=2" alt="" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/350?random=3" alt="" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/220/380?random=4" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="right-r">
        Right Side
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this in the CSS file because I think the problem lies within the classname's syntax being wrong. You do not need to add any flex styles to the two divs inside the main div:

```
.reasons{
    padding: 0 2rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.right-r{
    background-color: var(--orange);
}
```

Comment: Oh I see!! It is 'Reason' instead of 'reason'! Thanks so much!

Comment: This doesn't give the required result. You can read more about how flex and flex-basis work in general. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox